# Is there a way to test the physics engine in a C# script without simulating Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to create a structure that consists of several blocks.

Creating many structures takes a long time because it goes through a rendering process and runs a Unity simulation on a frame-by-frame basis.

This is why we want to skip the rendering process.

I want to test whether a structure made up of multiple blocks maintains its original shape over time(when no external forces are applied) in c# script.

I need help with the following

Comment: Have you tried ecs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The physical process and rendering process are independent of each other, you can call the [`Physics.Simulate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Simulate.html) method many times in a single frame.

Here is an example:

```
public class SimulatePhysics : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float totalTime;

    public void Start()
    {
        Physics.autoSimulation = false;
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        var remain = totalTime;
        while((remain -= Time.fixedDeltaTime) > 0f)
        {
            Physics.Simulate(Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        }

        // Check the simulation result here
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer was helpful to me thx bro!! :D